# Inputting df frame value into GET function web query

Tags: r, purrr, httr

I'm trying to input a list of values from a data frame into my get function for the web query and then cycle through each iteration as I go. If somebody would be able to link me some further resources to read and learn from this, it would be appreciated.

The following is the code which draws the data names from the API server. I plan on using `purrr` iteration functions to go over it. The input from the list would be inserted in the variable name `RFG_SELECT`.

````
library(httr)
library(purrr)

## Call up Query Development Script

## Calls up every single rainfall data gauge across the entirety of QLD

wmip_callup <- GET('https://water-monitoring.information.qld.gov.au/cgi/webservice.pl?{"function":"get_site_list","version":"1","params":{"site_list":"MERGE(GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,AYR),GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,BRISBANE),GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,BUNDABERG),GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,MACKAY),GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,MAREEBA),GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,ROCKHAMPTON),GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,SOUTH_JOHNSTONE),GROUP(MGR_OFFICE_ALL,TOOWOOMBA))"}}')

# Turns API server data into JSON data.

wmip_dataf <- content(wmip_callup, type = 'application/json')

# Returns the values of the rainfall gauge site names and is the directory function. 

list_var <- wmip_dataf[["_return"]][["sites"]]

# Combines all of the rainfall gauge data together in a list (could be used for giving file names / looping the data).

rfg_bind <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, list_var)

# Sets the column name of the combination data frame. 

rfg_bind <- setNames(rfg_bind, "Rainfall Gauge Name")                   

rfg_select <- rfg_bind$`Rainfall Gauge Name`

# Attempts to filter list into query:

wmip_input <- GET('https://water-monitoring.information.qld.gov.au/cgi/webservice.pl?{"function":"get_ts_traces","version":"1","params":{"site_list":**rfg_select**,"datasource":"AT","varfrom":"10","varto":"10","start_time":"0","end_time":"0","data_type":"mean","interval":"day","multiplier":"1"}}') ```
````

Answer (score 0):

## Hey there,

After some work I've found a solution using a concatenate string.

I setup a dummy variable that helped me select a data value.

```
# Dummy Variable string:

wmip_url <- 'https://water-monitoring.information.qld.gov.au/cgi/webservice.pl?{"function":"get_ts_traces","version":"1","params":{"site_list":"varinput","datasource":"AT","varfrom":"10","varto":"10","start_time":"0","end_time":"0","data_type":"mean","interval":"day","multiplier":"1"}}'


# Dummy String, grabs ones value from the list.

rfg_individual <- rfg_select[2:2]

# Replaces the specified input 
rfg_replace <- gsub("varinput", rfg_individual, wmip_url)

# Result 

"https://water-monitoring.information.qld.gov.au/cgi/webservice.pl?{\"function\":\"get_ts_traces\",\"version\":\"1\",\"params\":{\"site_list\":\"001203A\",\"datasource\":\"AT\",\"varfrom\":\"10\",\"varto\":\"10\",\"start_time\":\"0\",\"end_time\":\"0\",\"data_type\":\"mean\",\"interval\":\"day\",\"multiplier\":\"1\"}}"
```